# How to fill rows dynamically into existing table from XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, xml

I need to **fill rows dynamically** into the **body section of an existing HTML** table. The **rows and values are defined in a XML string**, that comes from the DB. I tried several things: from cloning the rows somehow, and various other attempts. No libraries! Its a legacy application that runs only in IE. Any ideas on that? Thx!

**This function should build and insert the rows:**

```
function makeRows (xmldoc, schema, id) {

    var body = document.getElementById(id);
    var xmlrows = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");

    for (var i = 0; i < xmlrows.length; i++) {
      var xmlrow = xmlrows[i];
      var row = document.createElement("tr");

      for (var x = 0; x < schema.columns.length; x++) {
        var sc = schema.columns[x];
        var tagname = sc.tagname;
        var xmlcell = xmlrow.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0];
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var celltext = xmlcell.text;
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(celltext));
        cell.innerText = celltext;
        row.appendChild(cell);
      }

      body.appendChild(row);
    }
  }
```

**The function call and schema:**

```
var schema = {
        rowtag: "ROW",
        columns: [
            { tagname: "C1", label: "C1" },
            { tagname: "C2", label: "C2" },
            { tagname: "C3", label: "C3" }
        ]
      };

var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmldoc.async = false;
xmldoc.loadXML(xml); // xml = XML as string, not declared here

makeRows(xmldoc, schema, "body");
```

**The HTML Table and XML:**

```
<table id="table">
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th name="A">A</th>
      <th name="B">B</th>
      <th name="C">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body">
    // Here: must be filled with rows from XML
  </tbody>
</table>

-------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<XML_FILE>
  <ROW>
    <C1></C1>
    <C2>some value</C2>
    <C3>some value</C3>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <C1>some value</C1>
    <C2>some value</C2>
    <C3>some value</C3>
  </ROW>
</XML_FILE>
```

Comment: Does your code work, except you get "undefined" instead of "some value"?

Comment: The example here is an abstraction of the orginal code. Yes, undefined was one problem. And also that I placed the value under the wrong header column.

Comment: Replacing `var celltext = xmlcell.text;` with `var celltext = xmlcell.textContent;` seems to fix the undefined problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/6c67ueum/

Comment: Thx! I still get undefined, but now actually in every row, what means it fills at least every cell.

Comment: Can't think of why this would make a difference in whether every cell was filled.  But at least your problem is now limited to getting the text content of the XML document.  Does my Fiddle work in your version of IE?

Comment: With your adaption I get undefined. If I switch back to `xmlcell.text`, it then brings me the values.

Comment: Oh, weird.  So is everything now working, or do you get a bunch of undefineds with my code but only one value with yours?

Comment: Bunch of undefineds with your code and some value with mine. Strange.

Comment: Yep.  I'd investigate the first value that's *not* output, to see if it's malformed.